# hover movimentando elemento

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Quando aplicado o `hover`, ele movimenta os elementos.

```css
.iconsHab i{
    color: #0098DA;
    padding: 5px;
    vertical-align: middle
}

.iconsHab i:hover{
    color: #0098DA;
    font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<!-- 
  Bootstrap docs: https://getbootstrap.com/docs
-->
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.2.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-hWVjflwFxL6sNzntih27bfxkr27PmbbK/iSvJ+a4+0owXq79v+lsFkW54bOGbiDQ" crossorigin="anonymous">
 
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
     <div class="hab">
  <p class="iconsHab">
<i class="fab fa-js"></i>
<i class="fab fa-node-js"></i>
<i class="fab fa-css3-alt"></i>
<i class="fab fa-html5"></i>
<i class="fab fa-vuejs"></i>
<i class="fab fa-angular"></i>
<i class="fab fa-react"></i>
<i class="fas fa-coffee"></i>
</p>
</div>                                                              
  </div>  
</div>
```

Comment: Você altera o `font-size` no `hover`. Isso não está deixando o texto maior? Aliás, isso é a única coisa que muda, porque a cor da fonte permanece a mesma.

Comment: É por causa do "font-size" que você colocou. Ao dar hover, ele aumenta o tamanho do ícone. E se você apenas mudar a cor do ícone ao invés de mudar o tamanho da fonte?

Comment: não tem texto, usei a tag  <p> apenas para estilizar melhor. Preciso justamente do efeito que ao passar o mouse aumenta o ícone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aumentar o tamanho da fonte para ter esse efeito não é o ideal.

Uma das soluções e usando o `transform:scale` para aumentar o tamanho dos ícones no `:hover`. No caso eu passei o ícone do tamanho normal 100% scale(1), para para 150% scale(1.5) *(cada 0.1 corresponde a 10% do tamanho original)*

Veja no exemplo abaixo como fica.

```css
.iconsHab i{
    color: #0098DA;
    padding: 5px;
    vertical-align: middle
}

.iconsHab i:hover{
    color: #0098DA;
    transform: scale(1.5);
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<!-- 
  Bootstrap docs: https://getbootstrap.com/docs
-->
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.2.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-hWVjflwFxL6sNzntih27bfxkr27PmbbK/iSvJ+a4+0owXq79v+lsFkW54bOGbiDQ" crossorigin="anonymous">
 
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
     <div class="hab">
  <p class="iconsHab">
<i class="fab fa-js"></i>
<i class="fab fa-node-js"></i>
<i class="fab fa-css3-alt"></i>
<i class="fab fa-html5"></i>
<i class="fab fa-vuejs"></i>
<i class="fab fa-angular"></i>
<i class="fab fa-react"></i>
<i class="fas fa-coffee"></i>
</p>
</div>                                                              
  </div>  
</div>
```

Comment: Sensacional, Hugo! Eu não sabia disso. Ficou muito boa a solução. Espero que isso resolva a questão para o wiliamvj

Comment: @RodrigoTognin valeu, parece que já resolveu ela até aceitou a resposta :). Caso te interesse pesquise sobre as propriedade `transform` do CSS, da para fazer muita coisa interessante com elas